# Can you convert a c++ rapid json object to a Python Json object?

Tags: python, json, python-c-api, rapidjson

I am building a C++ project that connects to a customer-owned Python codebase and sending a json object to the python code. Because the python codebase is customer-owned, I cannot modify the python codebase to receive a json string. I am using Python C/API for the interface.

I've built a small python file to convert the json string to json object using python's json library. I'd prefer to write the json object on the C++ side using rapidjson. Can I build a python json object from C++ rapid json and have it read by python's json library without converting the object to a string? If it's possible, which function would be the right one to convert the json Document to a Python Object?

```
C++:
PyObject* packJsonDict;
PyObject* customerDict;

int PYCPP::getJsonToInterface()
{
    std::string json= "{\"pet\": \"dog\", \"count\": 5}";
    PyObject* JsonObject = m_pImpl->pack_JsonString(json);

    std::string function_string = "read_json";
    PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1, JsonObject);

    //trying packing just the json string
    PyObject* runnableFunction = PyDict_GetItemString(customerDict,     (char*)function_string);
    PyObject* result = PyObject_CallObject(runnableFunction, args);
}

PyObject* PYCPP::pack_JsonString(std::string json_string)
{
    std::string function_string = "convert_jsonString_to_jsonObject";
    PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1, PyString_FromString((char*)    json_string.c_str()) );

    //trying packing just the json string
    PyObject* runnableFunction = PyDict_GetItemString(packJsonDict,     (char*)function_string);
    PyObject* result = PyObject_CallObject(runnableFunction, args);

    if(result == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "result was null!\n";
    }
    return result;
}

Python:
import json

def convert_jsonString_to_jsonObject(jsonString):

    print "converting:", jsonString

    return json.loads(jsonString)
```

Comment: Yes, you can. You have to (recursively) traverse the rapid json 
object and manually construct [PyDictObject](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html) out of it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out.